# Why would GNU Make miss last iteration of foreach?

Tags: makefile, foreach, build, gnu-make

Given the following Makefile:

```
PROGRAMS := aprogram
SYSTEMS := linux windows
ARCHS := 386 amd64

define PROGRAM_template =
CUR_PROG := _build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1)
$(CUR_PROG): export GOOS = $(2)
$(CUR_PROG): export GOARCH = $(3)
$(CUR_PROG):
    @echo "$(CUR_PROG)"
PROG_TARGETS += $(CUR_PROG)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(foreach sys,$(SYSTEMS),$(foreach arch,$(ARCHS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch))))))

all: $(PROG_TARGETS)
```

the output is:

```
[0] % make all
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_amd64/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_windows_386/aprogram
```

If I add another architecture `fakearch`, the output is:

```
[0] % make all
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_amd64/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_fakearch/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_windows_386/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_windows_amd64/aprogram
```

Which makes me think is is just not performing the last iteration. How do I correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double-eval will work.  But the more common method is to defer the expansion of the internal variable `CUR_PROG` by escaping it via `$$`, like this:

```
PROG_TARGETS :=

define PROGRAM_template =
CUR_PROG := _build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1)
$$(CUR_PROG): export GOOS = $(2)
$$(CUR_PROG): export GOARCH = $(3)
$$(CUR_PROG):
        @echo "$$(CUR_PROG)"
PROG_TARGETS += $$(CUR_PROG)
endef
```

The reason for this is you're using `call` first, then `eval`.  The `call` function will expand its arguments before `eval` sees them.

You have this inside your loops:

```
$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch)))
```

In order to expand this make first will expand the inner function:

```
$(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch))
```

This expands the `PROGRAM_template` as a straightforward string expansion: remember this is not `eval` so it's not interpreting the text as if it were a makefile, it's just expanding values.  So the assignment in the first line is not in effect because we haven't run the `eval` yet.  In your original implementation the first time through the loop, `CUR_PROG` will have no value before the `call`, so the `call` expands to:

```
CUR_PROG := _build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram
: export GOOS = linux
: export GOARCH = 386
:
        @echo ""
PROG_TARGETS +=
```

then that string is given to `eval` for evaluation, but it's basically a no-op except for setting `CUR_PROG`.

The next time through the loop, `CUR_PROG` still has the previous value so when call expands the string you get:

```
CUR_PROG := _build/bin/aprogram_linux_amd64/aprogram
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram: export GOOS = linux
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram: export GOARCH = amd64
_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram:
        @echo "_build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram"
PROG_TARGETS += _build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram
```

etc.  Basically, every time through the loop you're using the value of the `CUR_PROG` value from the *previous* loop, because the expansion happens during the `call` function, but the reassignment of the variable doesn't happen until the `eval` function.

By escaping the `CUR_PROG` it ensure that `call` will not expand it, which means it will be left for `eval` to expand.  E.g., with my version above after the `call` expansion is complete the result will be this:

```
CUR_PROG := _build/bin/aprogram_linux_386/aprogram
$(CUR_PROG): export GOOS = linux
$(CUR_PROG): export GOARCH = 386
$(CUR_PROG):
        @echo "$(CUR_PROG)"
PROG_TARGETS += $(CUR_PROG)
```

which is what you wanted.

A useful debugging tool for understanding `eval` is to replace it with the `info` function; this will cause make to print out the string that eval sees and it helps to visualize what's happening:

```
$(foreach ...,$(info $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch))))))
```

Another option for a solution here is to not use a `CUR_PROG` variable at all.  You could, in this example, take the recipe out of the `define` altogether.  This would work just as well:

```
define PROGRAM_template =
PROG_TARGETS += _build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1)
_build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1): export GOOS = $(2)
_build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1): export GOARCH = $(3)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(foreach sys,$(SYSTEMS),$(foreach arch,$(ARCHS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch))))))

$(PROG_TARGETS):
        @echo "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for the super detailed answer. That helps clarify a lot. I will say, the first bit of code doesn't work as expected. I only end up with one target in PROG_TARGETS when I do the escaped expansion. However, the last bit of code, without CUR_PROG, works perfectly, and seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: If it doesn't work that means you've not defined `PROG_TARGETS` as a simple variable.  All variables are considered recursive unless specified otherwise, and the `+=` operator uses the previous type.  If you add the line `PROG_TARGETS :=` to define it as a simple variable before you use it the first time, then the first example will work.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `eval` the temp variable inside the define because make expands all references simultaneously inside a function call.

```
PROGRAMS := aprogram
SYSTEMS := linux windows
ARCHS := 386 amd64

define PROGRAM_template =
$(eval CUR_PROG := _build/bin/$(1)_$(2)_$(3)/$(1))
$(CUR_PROG): export GOOS = $(2)
$(CUR_PROG): export GOARCH = $(3)
$(CUR_PROG):
    @echo "$(CUR_PROG)"
PROG_TARGETS += $(CUR_PROG)
endef

$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(foreach sys,$(SYSTEMS),$(foreach arch,$(ARCHS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog),$(sys),$(arch))))))

all: $(PROG_TARGETS)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I still can't sort out what that means, but it certainly did the trick. Can you expand a bit?

Comment: Without `eval` make will expand `$(CUR_PROG)` inside the define before any assignments occur.